# ImageView and Label not filling parent (UIScrollView)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIScrollView and I am trying to add a UIImageView inside the scrollview. But after that, I want a UILabel inside the imageview. Basically, the image should fill the scroll view and the label should appear in the center of the image. Here is what I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var image_scroll_view: UIScrollView!
var imageView = UIImageView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    image_scroll_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image_scroll_view.frame.size.width, image_scroll_view.frame.height)
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    image_scroll_view.scrollRectToVisible(imageView.frame, animated: true)

    self.imageView.image = // ...

    let curr_user_name = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.width, imageView.frame.height))
    curr_user_name.text = "John Smith"
    curr_user_name.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    curr_user_name.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16.0)
    curr_user_name.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    curr_user_name.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y)
    curr_user_name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    imageView.addSubview(curr_user_name)
    image_scroll_view.addSubview(imageView)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

The scrollview is yellow. Ideally, the image view should fill all of that (it doesn't even show up at the moment) and the label should fill all of the image view, which would automatically center the text.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make cur_user_name a property and
Write this code:

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image_scroll_view.frame.size.width, image_scroll_view.frame.height)

curr_user_name.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y)
```

in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: So the image shows up now, but doesn't fill up the imageView. I see the image in the middle with green border around. Additionally, the label still doesn't cover the area. Here is what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/tMJ55ej.png

Comment: That does 75% of the trick. But is it possible to zoom the image until the 2 sides touch the borders?

Comment: Yes.. imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill shall make it happen

Comment: It depends upon the design. But usually we dont